# How create and format a new partition

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, partitioning, disk-management

I wiped my laptop and I am repartitioning its 1TB hard disk. I created four primary partitions without problems.  But I cannot create a fift primary partition. When I try I get a message stating: `disk will be converted basic disk to dynamic`.

I tried to make a partition using partition magic and more tools.but it not worked.how to make a new partition without deleting or formation my another partition.[this is the error message pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B22Em.png)

Answer (score 1):

Because in the Basic (MBR DOS style) partitioning you appear to have, you can only have 4 primary partitions, or 3 Primary and 1 Extended partition which can contain many more logical partitions (15-63 in most OS's, although technically it is limited only by disk space) which it appears you have already, 4 primary partitions. In order for Windows to add more partitions, you need to convert the disk to Windows Dynamic partitioning or wipe the disk and use a GUID/GPT style partition table which allows for 127 partitions.

You may want to look into basic partitioning information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) and more information on Basic vs Dynamic [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757696.aspx).

And converting shouldn't be a problem... note what it says "you will not be able to start installed operating systems from any volumes on the disk(s) **except the current boot volume**" so it should work fine. If you plan on installing a different OS such as Linux, it will be bootable through grub or other method used by the distro, Windows is basically just warning you that if you do this, it is going to overwrite the boot code on the disk.